# implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01' showing error

Tags: java, android, xml

please help me. i was created an android project completely. but problems is my app gradle file showing this error sshot below.

[image: Error]

and i have one more problem. i was set InterstitialAd but it's not showing in my activity. please inform me how to solve this problem??

gradle.build

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
}
```

activity java

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(Howtogeek.this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });

        Howtogeek = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.Howtogeek);
        bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.bar);
        Howtogeek.setWebViewClient(new Howtogeek.myWebclient());
        bar.setMax(100);
        Howtogeek.loadUrl("https://www.howtogeek.com/");

        WebSettings webSettings = Howtogeek.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Howtogeek.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        Howtogeek.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        Howtogeek.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        Howtogeek.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can help me anyone immediately? i'm in short time. i need to upload my project as soon as possible.

Comment: Do you tried sync and build? Could you share error text?

Comment: i'm tried... already synced, clean and rebuild. but not working. @Mete

Comment: and my main problem is, ads not showing.

Comment: If hover the red line you must see an error. Please check it...
Could you try ":28.0.0-rc01" instead of ":28.0.0-beta01"?
Also there is a not good solution; if you change your target version to 27 and support verison ":27.1.1" it must work.

Comment: yes, i was tested ":28.0.0-rc01" and ":28.0.0-beta01". but same problems.

Comment: google proprietary apis are a pain in the neck

Answer (score 2):

If you have use this

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.2'
```

and also use one more dependency

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.2'
```

this is work for me. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you.
you have to add all the libraries which are shown in "examples include"
[not same version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmeFi.png)

Comment: i have changed all the 'beta01' to 'rc01' too and it compile successfully

Comment: Here my added library using "examples include":     implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-rc01'

Comment: so you can change all the lower libraries's version to the latest version

Answer (score 1):

i had it too. problem was with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

i changed it to

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
```

and it works well

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Google Play implemented target version of API 26 so use API 27 still good

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
```

And also use the later version of play services

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem....
as you know Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX.
You can continue to use the support library (those versioned 27 and earlier) **BUT**
google Developer recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects.

*With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project to use AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.*

#### Further reading:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/
  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

It worked for me. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project and rebuild.

Comment: i'm tried... already synced, clean and rebuild. but not working.

Comment: Well i get the exact error after adding gms:play-services

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()

}
```

and

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
```